# Perl - Remove lines of an array under conditions

Tags: arrays, perl

How can I remove lines of an array when a column satisfies a regex ?

Example :

```
'0','john','192.168.0.1'
'1','james','192.168.1.1'
'2','pat','192.168.0.1'
```

I want to remove all the lines which contains xxx.xxx.1.x in the third column (or saving lines which do not contain...)

Maybe egrep will be the best solution (since I don't want to use a time-consuming loop), but I don't know how to specify a column and a regex.

Comment: Lines of an array or of a file?

Comment: Show the regexp you tried

Comment: @choroba : array, as said in the title...@red0ct : my question was about to know to specify a regex in grep, not how to forge a regex

Answer (score 5):

You cannot avoid a "time consuming loop" - what do you think "grep" does, but loop - line by line - and perform a test?

However, there's a perl `grep` function that you can use, that - in addition to regular expressions - also allows for code solutions.

So something like this works:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;

use Data::Dumper;

my @stuff = (
    [ '0', 'john',  '192.168.0.1' ],
    [ '1', 'james', '192.168.1.1' ],
    [ '2', 'pat',   '192.168.0.1' ]
);

print Dumper \@stuff;

my @new_array = grep { not $_->[2] =~ m/\.1\.\d+$/ } @stuff;

print "Entries which match:\n";
print Dumper \@new_array;
```

Be under no illusions though - grep is 'looping' through your array. It's just hiding the fact that that's what it's doing. (`egrep` would do the same though, so you don't lose anything).

Comment: Thanks, it works perfectly.  I just wanted to avoid loops made by myself since I know perl has some subtleties (better programmed than me...)

Answer (score 0):

A regex for IP with '1' in the 3rd position could be:

```
/\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.1\.\d{1,3}/
```